# Issue with world readable sudoers file

Tags: centos, sudo

This is what I get in my CentOS Linux machine whenever I execute any commands. Can you please help me to intercept and solve this?

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/admin is world readable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your system has a root password, you can use `su -` to get a root shell and fix it.  Run `su -`, enter the root password, then run `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/*`.  You should now be able to exit from the `su` shell and run `sudo` as needed.

If your system does not have a root password, you'll have to reboot to a rescue CD (or perhaps to the initrd in emergency mode), mount the root fs, and fix the permissions of any files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` as above, then unmount it and reboot again.

Alternatively, if you have `sshd` configured to allow root logins, you may be able to ssh in as root from another system if it has its public key in the target system's `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.   It's fairly common for ssh root logins to be disabled, though.

Comment: BTW, if the permissions are messed up, it's also possible that some of your files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` may have the wrong owner or group.  If that's the case, fix it with `chmod -R root:root /etc/sudoers.d/`.

Comment: This you so much, now it is working